# Adding jar with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

My Eclipse project has the following structure:

-- | My project

```
  |-src

  |-build

  |-doc

  |-lib
```

In lib are placed my jar files. These files have been added to the Build path with "Add to Buildpath command". The project successfully compiles.

I want to build the project with Ant, to this aim I wrote the following xml file

```
<project name="ABTestConnector" basedir=".">
<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="test.Prova"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="/lib"/>
<property name="doc.dir"     value="/doc"/>

<fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
 </fileset>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<path id="class-path">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <include name="*.jar" />
  </fileset>   
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
        <classpath refid="class-path"/>
    </javac>    
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>

</target>
<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
<target name="doc" depends="clean-build" description="generate javadoc">
       <javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
</target>
```

I have also tried in the fileset: include name="**/*.jar"/>

But I still get the errors

```
[javac] /home/bruno/Documenti/TestingEnvironment/EclipseWorkspace/SeleniumABTestConnector_0.0.1/src/driversTod/TodSelenium.java:10: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you change your lib path to some absolute path and see if it works. My guess is that it's not getting selenium jars in class path.

Comment: What's in this path. It's not mentioned in ANT anywhere. /home/bruno/Documenti/TestingEnvironment/EclipseWorkspace/SeleniumABTestConnector_0.0.1/src/driversTod/TodSelenium.java also src,build path will be under your current directory, is this you want?